# Cache online fonts in <link> tag

Tags: html, css, caching, fonts

I load two fonts from [google fonts](http://google.com/fonts) with `<link>` tag in document header.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The problem is website always load fonts from URL and don't cache them (I think).
How can I cache these fonts and force to load them from local if they are present?

Thank you :D

Comment: Who told you that it's not cached? [See the docs](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#what-about-performance-will-web-fonts-slow-down-my-page)

Comment: If they are on cache, why fonts don't load whem I'm offline?

Comment: Wrong expectations. Browsers fail requests if you are offline, unless you use appcache manifest.

Comment: Ok, I'd been reading about appcache manifest but I don't know how to implement it to cache fonts. I'd tryed to set the manifest="ejemplo.appcache" in the html tag with the file but it didn't work. Can you put me and example? Thank you so much.